# Typo on Krylov's article On Quasi Diffusion Process 1966

Tags: probability

In the article, "On Quasi-Diffusion Processes" (Krylov, 1966) one reads:
[image]

in item (a) instead of

for all $\lambda_i$ and $x$,

shouldn't it be

for all $\lambda$ and $x$?

Comment: It seems fine as he wrote: he is requiring that the quadratic form is positive definite, uniformly on $x$.

Comment: It's pretty much the same, since $\lambda$ is a vector, so it is arbitrary if and only if its components are arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your point and in my opinion $\lambda$ instead of $\lambda_i$ would be better. But it's not wrong, just an other style. I saw notation like this in many, often -but not only - a bit older, papers.